# How to show 404 message, but don't show header and footer?

Tags: reactjs

**What should be added here so that the header footer does not show?**

```
import React from 'react';
import './NotFound.css'
import image from '../../../src//Images//404.jpg'

const NotFound = () => {
    return (
        <div >
            <img className="not-found" src={image} alt="" />

        </div>
    );
};

export default NotFound;
```

Comment: share your App.js or/and index.js code.

Comment: Could be because of routing, the routing component(app/index.js) might be adding layout for all routes.

Comment: One way is to use [React Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

You can render this message conditionally in parent component, for example:

```
<React.Fragment>
    { NotFoundError ? <NotFound/> : <MainComponent/> }
</React.Fragment>
```